# May I use freepascal and delphi tags together in this question?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question

First I would like to say that even though the present question is addressed to a specific question, one may find it relevant to other questions too.

The tag system, if used wisely, may increase the chances of a question be carried out to the proper audience and also the chances of getting quality answers quickly.

Recently, I asked the following [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36979161/why-are-threads-synchronizing-only-with-large-intervals) and tagged it with the [freepascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal) and [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) tags. Let me explain why:

1. code was compiled with a free pascal compiler (then Freepascal), even though I was not expecting answers from this small audience (at least inside Stack Overflow);
2. Delphi audience is bigger and usually prepared to solve analogue problems (then Delphi);

Since I was sure that the problem described in the question (multi-threads issue) could be solved by both communities, I thought motif **1** as merely informative and motif **2** as pragmatic (since it increased my chances, I am considering this as a fact).

Following the recommendation of [David Heffernan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505088/david-heffernan) commentaries, I removed the tag (but only after getting an accepted answer).

Am I doing something wrong? I would really appreciate your recommendations on this topic.

Comment: OT: Total nostalgia looking at the question (and answer). Worked with TP/BP/Delphi for 10 yrs, luckily this is 15 years back too :)

Answer (score 9):

Short answer: No, you may not.

You can put [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) and [freepascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal) together on a question if you have code that has to run on both Delphi and FPC and you are solving common issue.

While Delphi and FPC have many similarities and you can have cross-compilable code, they also have many differences. Question you have asked is about threading issue on Linux and Delphi does not even have Linux compiler. Tagging that question with [delphi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delphi) is inappropriate.

Using Delphi to gain more visibility will not do you any good because pure Delphi users will not be able to help you at all. And developers that are using FPC and can be of help probably follow [freepascal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/freepascal) anyway. You also risk gathering down votes on such questions because wrong tag can make your question seem less clear.

Comment: Please, consider that the specific question *have* similarities, even cross-platform. Indeed, a Delphi specialist answered correctly the question. Maybe someone would refrain to help just because an assumed wrong tag, but the concrete example shows the contrary.

Comment: Also, down votes with no comments after the user have added details to the question are not recommended by the community.

Comment: How do you know that person that answered that question would not answer it anyway?

Comment: Regarding down votes, people can down vote as they please. They don't have to leave comment if they don't want to.

Comment: I don't know for sure, that is why I was talking about chances. No free pascal tag here: http://stackoverflow.com/users/1744164/sir-rufo?tab=tags

Comment: Problem is that when you tag question with wrong tag, you may get answers specific for that tag that does not help you at all. And then you have situation where you are not satisfied because you have wrong answer, person answering is not satisfied because you mislead him and he/she wasted time. It is important to be precise.

Comment: I admit that I should have been more precise from the beginning. I have edited the question to add Linux and FPC specifics afterward. However, in this specific question, I could be precise describing the problem and also pragmatic using a popular tag (considering that the target problem *have* similarities, indeed).

Comment: I have fpc and lazarus tag and I haven't used any of those. Pure coincidence. I also follow fpc and pascal tags because there may be questions I am capable of answering even though I only use Delphi.

Comment: Of course, sometimes people ask wrong questions even when they are prepared, and only after a while you figure out that you need to add some additional information. Point is if you add tag just to gain visibility then don't do that. Add it only if you are solving common problem. That does not mean that you are not ever allowed to make mistake in tagging, just don't do that on purpose up front.

Comment: So, seems that you have changed your mind... I agree with you, to tag *only* for visibility is not good for obvious reasons. As I said, I *did not* do such a thing. I tagged for visibility *and* similarities.

Comment: Not really. I haven't changed my mind. You are specifically using FPC and you added Delphi tag for visibility and you were hoping for similarities. You were not solving common problem even though at the end it turned out that answer works for both.

Comment: No, I wasn't hoping. Note that I am not saying they are identical. I just know that the RTLWaitForEvent() function in freepascal **IS** similar to the WaitForSingleObject() in delphi.

Comment: So, should I edit my question and describe that?

Comment: Delphi doesn't have a Linux compiler? What's [Kylix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kylix_%28software%29) then?

Comment: @eis Ancient history.

Comment: @cpicanco You don't have to edit your question. Don't get me wrong. I don't think you have done anything outrageous. But since you asked for guidance, I am telling you that adding Delphi tag was wrong in this case.

Comment: Yes, I asked for guidance and I really thank you for your time and patience! You have described two cases. When solving common problems, people are allowed to use the tags. When looking only for visibility, people are not. For the reason I have described, I am inclined to say that I am allowed to use the two tags. I am afraid to disagree.